# Kafka Exception while connecting to docker image

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

> `org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: Attempting to use idempotence with a broker which does not support the required message format (v2). The broker must be version 0.11 or later.`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't just throw your error message at us but explain a little, what you tried and how (see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). On the one hand, this will allow us to help you much better, on the other hand we won't feel like being mis-used as robots. Furthermore, the error message leads you the way: The Broker has not the right version. Without further information, it's quite impossible to help you.

Comment: `The broker must be version 0.11 or later`...

So, use a newer version of Kafka image such as `bitnami/kafka:latest`